# Xcode 6.1.1 update causes app to access VCs that no longer exist

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, storyboard

The project I am working with is built with Storyboards.  I do not have any Xib files, nor is the a ViewController that is built through code without a StoryboardVC counterpart.  There are no ViewControllers that are built entirely programmatically.

I have recently implemented the interface for the login screen as per design's request, and the design is visible in the Storyboard.  When a user runs the app in iOS 8, they can login, and then sign out and still see the current login screen.  **However, when a user runs the app in iOS 7, they do see the designed login screen initially, but when they logout, they see the old login screen.**

**The old login screen no longer exists in Storyboard.**  Furthermore breakpoints in the login screen are only called when the user first arrives.  No breakpoints are called when the user logs out again.

I am perplexed at what could be causing this, and apologize for not being able to attach screenshots.

Comment: If you are working on a team and use some sort of version control such as git, it is possible that someone got merge conflicts and merged the xml the wrong way.  I would open the xml version of the storyboard and look for any hints of the old VC.  Highly unlikely but based on what you are saying, I am assuming you already tried the simple stuff.

Comment: Good idea.  One of the buttons from the old VC has a different title.  I went ahead and opened the XML, but I could not find the button with the old title.  Instead, I was only able to find the new title of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't bothered to delete the old cached versions of your built project. I suggest that you do so, and all will be well.

Comment: In particular, follow my instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6247073/341994

Comment: omg thank you!  I was ready to rebuild the entire UI if I didn't get an answer in the next couple days.  I did the deep clean a few times already (Clean Build Folder) as well as Reset Content and Settings.  The rest was new to me.

Comment: Call me crazy but I now do all that stuff every week or so. :) Also helps keep Swift editor from crashing so much (you aren't using Swift so you don't know what you're missing).

Comment: Good point, maybe I should dump this more often too.  And yes, I will definitely be going Swift once these current projects are done!